# Rails has_many :through association uses wrong foreign key for query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Rails 7.0.4

I have two Rails model, `Person` and `Marriage`. The idea is that a Person can have many wives and husbands through a Marriage join model, and can call `Person.wives` and `Person.husbands` to get the respective data.

Code for models:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :marriages
    has_many :husbands, through: :marriages, class_name: 'Person' 
    has_many :wives, through: :marriages, class_name: 'Person' 
end

class Marriage < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :husband, class_name: 'Person'
    belongs_to :wife, class_name: 'Person'
end
```

Code for Marriage migration:

```
class CreateMarriages < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :marriages do |t|
      t.references :husband, foreign_key: { to_table: :people }, index: true
      t.references :wife, foreign_key: { to_table: :people }, index: true
      t.date :marriage_date
      t.date :termination_date

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Persons have been created and a Marriage was created using this on the console:

```
husband = Person.first
wife = Person.second
Marriage.create(husband: husband, wife: wife)
```

However, calling `husband.wives` returns this

```
Person Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" INNER JOIN "marriages" ON "people"."id" = "marriages"."wife_id" WHERE "marriages"."person_id" = ?  [["person_id", 1]]                                                     
(Object doesn't support #inspect)                                  
=>
```

It seems the the last part of the query, looking for `marriages.person_id`, is wrong, as I expected it to use `marriages.husband_id`. How to make it so that it uses the correct foreign key?

I have tried adding options to the associations, such as `foreign_key: :wife_id`, `source: :husband`, and `inverse_of: :wife` to `has_many :husbands` and similarly on the `has_many :wives`, but the same result appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually use a single `has_many` assocation with two different foreign keys on the *other* table. Instead you need two different assocations:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :marriages_as_wife, 
     class_name: 'Marriage',
     foreign_key: :wife_id,
     inverse_of: :wife
   has_many :marriages_as_husband, 
     class_name: 'Marriage',
     foreign_key: :husband_id,
     inverse_of: :husband
    
   has_many :husbands, 
     through: :marriages_as_wife, 
     class_name: 'Person' 
   has_many :wives, 
     through: :marriages_as_husband, 
     class_name: 'Person' 
end
```

`inverse_of` doesn't actually change the generated queries in any way. Its simple used to setup the reference in memory to avoid a potential additional database query.

On a side note I would probally use a very different solution with a many to many join table instead to avoid making the hetronormative assumptions:

```
class Person
  has_many :marriage_memberships
  has_many :marriages, 
    through: :marriage_memberships
  has_many :spouses, 
    through: :marriages,
    source: :people
end

class Marriage
  has_many :marriage_memberships
  has_many :people, through: :marriage_memberships
end 

# I can't come up with a better name
class MarriageMemberships
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :marriage
end
```

Comment: Works well, accepted and upvoted. Extra thanks for the code with `spouse` instead, that's what I was originally going for, but got confused when I thought I'd need two `spouse_id`s on the join table.

Comment: @AW_Flister no worries, it also supports polygamy straight out of the box :)